Python Intermittent GUI Prompt
I have written a Python program that reads csv files into a Pandas Dataframe and performs a variety of actions on the data, which are banking transactions I have downloaded from my bank.
One action involves assigning a category to each spending transaction (e.g., Travel, Home, Entertainment, Auto, etc.). For the routine transactions, I use a dictionary lookup to determine the correct category. For the non-routine ones, I’d like to prompt the user to select from a GUI drop-down list of categories.
I have tried Tkinter and read about other GUI options, but they seem to be used as front-end GUIs. I’d like to have my transaction categorizing function display a drop-down list when a transaction is not resolved by my dictionary lookup, get the user input, and then “kill” the GUI display until it is needed again.
Is there a way to do this?
-

Tkinter can do pop-up windows, too. Or you can put some option selection in the terminal rather than a GUI

One option for this is easygui. This library allows GUI programming with simple and linear function calls. Each function call creates a pop-up box which disappears once resolved. For your example, the code would be this simple:
import easygui
choice = easygui.choicebox("Which category is this?", "Category",
                           ["Travel", "Home", "Entertainment", "Auto"])
print(choice) # prints the string chosen


It also provides several other functions such as yes/no boxes, plain message boxes, choice button boxes, and file open dialogs. These are all documented here.
According to its project page, easygui isn't being maintained or updated any more, and lists some alternatives. However, it still works just fine and is actually more recently updated than some of the alternatives listed. It uses a Tkinter backend, so you won't need to install any extra packages like the other libraries.

Your easygui recommendation is simple and works perfectly.
